# Seleccionar string menos ultimos n caracteres

Tags: regex, plsql

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy necesitando una expresion regular que me obtenga todos los caracteres de un string, con excepcion de los ultimos n caracteres, por ejemplo, dado el string **laravel**, que me traiga todos, menos los ultimos dos, a ser **larav**

Intenté con lo siguiente

```
   [^\w{2}$]
```

Pero obtengo como resultado **l**, no comprendo bien en que me estoy equivocando.

** Aclaración: Estoy utilizando PL/SQL en una base Oracle, específicamente la función **regexp_substr()**

Comment: Python? C#? Assembler? Javascript? R? Go? Que codigo tienes? Talvez tu regex no esté mal, pero sii el uso alrededor de tus variables

Comment: si, tenés razon, no especifiqué el lenguaje, estoy usando PL/SQL de Oracle, aunque su implementacion de expresiones regulares es bastante standard.

Comment: A pesar de que si es bastante estándar, hay pequeños detalles que no están implementados en todos los lenguajes (como los _negative lookbehind_ `(?<!ABC)`), pero para tu pregunta no se requieren cosas así.

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo la siguiente solución:

```
select substr(Campo, 1, length(Campo) - 2) 
from tabla;
```

Aquí lo que hacemos es una consulta que devolverá todas las cadenas guardadas en cada registro de la **columna campo** desde su primera posición hasta el tamaño de la cadena original menos los dos últimos caracteres.

Usamos la **función substr** para obtener la subcadena dentro de la cadena original y usamos también la **función length** la cual nos devuelve el tamaño de la cadena original y a este tamaño le restamos la cantidad de caracteres que no queremos copiar.

Ej: Supongamos que tenemos una cadena cuyo valor sea: **"Palabra"**, aplicando la consulta que te propongo quedaría:

```
length(campo) //obtiene el tamaño de la cadena que es 7
```

Entonces:

```
 substr(Campo, 1, 7 - 2)
 substr(Campo, 1, 5)
```

Obteniéndose como resultado final: **"Palab"**.

Comment: Gracias, el tema es que necesito que sea una expresión regular, en este caso no puedo usar la funcion substr.

Comment: La solución propuesta la mas simple y directa; no veo para qué complicarse la vida con expresiones regulares.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
               str, -- nombre de la columna de tu tabla, o un string si solo es para pruebas
               '^(\w+)\w{2}$', -- regrex a usar
               1, -- a partir de que caracteres buscar, default 1 
               1, -- cantidad de ocurrencias a buscar, default 1
               'i', -- banderas, i es para ignorar mayúsculas/minúsculas
               1 -- subexpresión a substraer
           )
    FROM foo;
```

El punto es usar el último parámetro, que toma la subcadena de la i-ésima expresión

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('foo bar 123', '(\w+) (\w+) (\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
-- regresa 'foo'

REGEXP_SUBSTR('foo bar 123', '(\w+) (\w+) (\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
-- regresa 'bar'

REGEXP_SUBSTR('foo bar 123', '(\w+) (\w+) (\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 3)
-- regresa '124'
```

Ver más [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099).

Comment: Veré si puedo utilizar algo de esto, el tema es que en el ejemplo, hay una separacion por espacio, y yo necesito trabajar con un mismo string, y evitar los dos ultimos caracteres, voy a darle vuelta a esta sugerencia.

Comment: @Javier para aceptar cualquier caracter, incluyendo espacios, hay que reemplazar cada `\w` por un punto `.`